# Can I apply @Bean annotation to the functions as well?

Tags: java, spring

I am new to Spring Java and a little bit confused about where to use `@Bean` annotation. 
See the following code for instance:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    private final Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.max_fetch_depth", env.getProperty("hibernate.max_fetch_depth"));
        properties.put("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache",env.getProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"));
        properties.put("hibernate.cache.use_minimal_puts", env.getProperty("hibernate.cache.use_minimal_puts"));
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.release_mode", env.getProperty("hibernate.connection.release_mode"));
        properties.put("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache",env.getProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache"));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lcemfb = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        lcemfb.setJpaVendorAdapter(getJpaVendorAdapter());
        lcemfb.setDataSource(dataSource());
        lcemfb.setPersistenceUnitName("entityManagerFactory");
        lcemfb.setPackagesToScan("com.sha.microservicecoursemanagement.model");
        lcemfb.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return lcemfb;
    }


    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter getJpaVendorAdapter() {
        JpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        return adapter;
    }

}
```

Now in the above code, `dataSource`, `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`, `PlatformTransactionManager` and `JpaVendorAdapter` these functions have attribute as `@Bean`. 
Now, what I have read on the internet is `@Bean` can only be given to the class types, not to the functions.
Can someone clear my confusion, please?

Comment: Java has methods, not functions. The @Bean there means that the object returned by that method (those methods) is (are) Beans

Comment: Here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch02s02.html

Comment: Thanks Stultuske, so as per Beans definition. The objects which these methods are returning, those will be static ?? As @Bean makes the scope static.

Comment: `@Bean` isn't allowed on types, it is only allowed on methods (or as meta-annotation on other annotations). You cannot add `@Bean` to a `class`.

Comment: M. Deinum, according to google we can add @Bean to classes as well.

Answer (score 2):

The `@Bean` can be applied to method, if the class is annotated with `@Configuration`. [Refer this link](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-basic-concepts)

Following example where I am using `@Bean`

```
@Configuration
public class ClientDataSourceConfig {

    @Value("${spring.datasource.driver}")
    private String driver;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String password;

    public ClientDataSourceRouter dataSource;

    @Bean(name = "getDataSource")
    public ClientDataSourceRouter getDataSource() throws Exception {
        dataSource = new ClientDataSourceRouter();
        dataSource.init(driver, url, username, password);
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: what about the concept of @Bean singleton scope, the concept says scope is singleton. How this applies here ?

Comment: In Spring, the default scope is Singleton. What it means is, during the application start, the instance of the class is loaded(created), and where required, will be injected using `@Autowired`. To change the default scope, you can add `Prototype` https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html

Comment: the method you're annotating with @Bean is a constructor basically. You tell *how* to create it, but not how many or when -- spring takes care of that

Comment: So in my above code. All the methods which are marked as @Bean, they will return the singleton object ?

Comment: By default, Yes.

Comment: `@Bean` works on `@Component` as well, they aren't limited to `@Configuration` only.

Comment: Yes. `@Component` is the parent of `@Configuration`, `@Service`, etc. So, technically, even `@Component` will do

Answer (score -1):

Yes `@Bean` can only be given to the Class types. In your functions you can see that you are returning class instances such as DataSource, LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean etc. You are not adding `@Bean` annotation to the function. what you are doing is, telling Spring to return a bean from that class. for an example,

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));

    return dataSource;
}
```

In here you are telling Spring to return a DataSource Object. Unless if you have @Bean annocation , you can't autowire the datasource object. Therefor @Bean allow you to use `@Autowired DataSource dataSource;`. These beans are managed by Spring IoC container.

Comment: what about the concept of @Bean, the concept says scope is singleton. How this applies here ?

Comment: When application is initially loading it looks for classes which contains annotations such as `@component, @service, @Configuration, @Controller, @Bean` etc. Then Spring will create instances from these classes. These Objects are singleton objects which means only one instance exists. If you create this datasource object using new keyword, `DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();` every time that line executes application will create a new datasource object. What Singleton object does is prevent that. It will save application memory.